# How to add option in xorg.conf with nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I am using `nvidia-352` with `nvidia-prime`. To fix the tearing issue(well known) I was trying to add options in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. But after restart `nvidia` or `prime` replace `xorg.conf` file.

My question is that, how can I add options in `xorg.conf` so that it will persist after restart? There should be a `xorg configuration` generation script. `nvidia-prime` wiki page doesn't have any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Applications like `nvidia-settings` have a bad habit of overwriting it. Use separate `.conf` files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` instead. From [`man xorg.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/xorg.conf.5.html):

```
Additional configuration  files  are  searched  for  in  the  following
directories when the server is started as a normal user:

    /etc/X11/<cmdline>
    /etc/X11/<cmdline>
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

where  <cmdline> is a relative path (with no “..” components) specified
with the -configdir command line option.

When the Xorg  server  is  started  by  the  “root”  user,  the  config
directory search locations are as follows:

    <cmdline>
    /etc/X11/<cmdline>
    /etc/X11/<cmdline>
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

where  <cmdline> is the path specified with the -configdir command line
option (which may be absolute or relative).
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I already have /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Does xog.conf.d/nvidia.config override default xorg.conf options? I found out that xorg.conf.d/ directory contains specific file name like 20-intel.conf. What should be the file name for nvidia device?

Comment: @shantanu you can name it whatever you like - you can use a leading number to ensure and ordering (like `30-nvidia-is-annoying.conf`). From what I understand of the manpage, the files in the directory are read after `xorg.conf`, so it should override options in that file.