# Built-in laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have a HP Omen 15 with AMD Ryzen7 and Nividia Geforce RTX 2060, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Have been operating with dual boot (Ubuntu + Windows) and dual screen (in-built + external) really well for some time. Suddenly, today, the inbuilt screen doesn’t seem to be recognized anymore, while the external monitor works well.
The inbuilt screen shows boot options (and works on Windows) but “freezes” with a black screen + Omen symbol at login. The login screen shows up on the external monitor.

It is clearly some system configuration problem. So I tried all solutions I could find for a day, of which most of the proposed solutions seems to be around deleting / changing the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
See here for example: [Internal laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965/internal-laptop-screen-not-detected-when-using-nvidia-driver).
Nothing worked.

I’ve ran out of options for things to try, can’t seem to find a way around this… Can somebody help me out?

[My NVIDIA Xserver setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYr6v.png) doesn’t seem to find the inbuilt screen.

My nvidia-smi output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P8     2W /  N/A |    324MiB /  5934MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1004      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 29MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1740      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 97MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1878      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              107MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4793      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       79MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5417      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings            0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Edit 1:**

Changing to intel graphics, the built-in screen returns but the external monitor stops working.

```
sudo prime-select intel 
reboot
```

This indicates that the problem is my NVIDIA card not being able to detect the buit-in screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, it was a configuration problem. Here’s what I found to work for my case:

**1 -** Edited the content of my `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` file:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

and then run on terminal: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/1310431/1175096

**2 -** I emptied out the content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Ref: [Internal laptop screen not detected when using Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059965)

**3 -** I created a new conf file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, named `30-nvidia-prime-overwrite-fucker.conf`. This is because gpu-manager usually overwrites `11-nvidia-prime.conf` at boot. The name really doesn’t matter, as long as you use a larger number at the beginning. My new file contained:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "Nvidia Prime"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    # Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"
    ModulePath "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

which is exactly the content of `11-nvidia-prime.conf` but with the `Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"` commented out.

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/689505/1175096

**4 -** In my `/etc/default/grub` file I wrote:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And then on terminal, to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

My built-in screen is back and my external monitor is working as an extension screen!

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

I have one laptop with external Monitor as well. Ususally it happens this, just when you selected (or it select by it self) the external Monitor as Primary and check it under `X Server XVideo Settings` voice . If you can see from my pic below, also me I have the external monitor as the unique selected but the build-in monitor still functional if I will switch or I will change the parameters.

Check also on the first voice Selection from `X Server Display Configuration`, I can see from your pic that the Down Arrow from the first voice selection it's colored , in that can show some other Monitors ; please try to open as I made in my pic. And double check on Ubuntu Settings under Monitor Section. Because Nvidia and Ubuntu system sometimes if set in different way from each other, could go in conflict with parameters....

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Niewbie for your reply. In the NVIDIA Settings, where you suggested, the only two options are "X screen 0" and "Dell" (the external monitor)

Comment: When did you installed the Nvidia drivers, you installed them with everything disconnected first.....Because I don't want that happened something during the Nvidia Driver installtion if the external Display was plugged. Because happened to me one time, and I reinstalled everything from zero..... Uncheck the box if (checked) under `Make this the primary display for the X screen` and restart the laptop...

Comment: Please post the output of `xrandr --listmonitors` and `xrandr --listactivemonitors`

Comment: @abu_bua , if I make the same also mine will show up only one Monitor, because I made the Primary Monitor as the External and it completely turn off the rest witouth list them out, but I have the possibility to switch or reactivate the build-in.....strange usually this problem it's reverse to the External Monitors and not to the build-in.

Comment: $ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-0 1680/473x1050/296+0+0  HDMI-0

$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-0 1680/473x1050/296+0+0  HDMI-0

Comment: In my settings I don't have the option "Make this the primary display for the X screen"

Comment: For sure happened something wrong during the Nvidia Drivers Installation. If you cannot find in anywhere , I suggest you to re-install the Drivers with everything un-plugged

Comment: Also be sure about the Secure Boot and Fast Boot that you don't ave activated from the Bios, otherwise the Drivers cannot be installed well.....

Comment: @Niewbie can you please explain this last comment? I not sure I understand it

Comment: I just reinstalled the nvidia drivers, in safety mode, no external monitor plugged in... no luck

Comment: It does not detect your embedded monitor (something like `eDP1` should be printed).

Comment: If you enter in the Bios of your Laptop you should find the Voice Secure Boot and Fast Boot, when you install Linux and the Drivers, if you are not Disable them, some modification/ changes of the  Drivers will not be installed proprerly and you can face such problems.....Please check into it.....